# How to put a drop down ant-design 'Select' component?

Tags: dropdown, antd

```
<Select
    mode="multiple"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    placeholder="Please select"
    defaultValue={['a10', 'c12']}
    onChange={handleChange}>    
    {children}
</Select>,
```

How to put a drop-down on an `antd` component?

Comment: Its not clear what you want, But I think if you refer to the documentation examples, you can find the answer.

Comment: I would like of icon dropdown on an antd component that does not have

Comment: Icon for your children options?